# Can you extend Message processors with JavaScript in Mule ESB?

Tags: javascript, mule, mule-studio, rhino

I am interested to hear how much of the Java code can be writen in JavaScript in a Mule project. Often when we want a custom message processor we can just extend it with a Java class, but can we do the same with Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unclear as to what you are trying to evaluate here. This depends on your choice of scripting language. Mule supports several scripting languages and you can do almost everything using scripting components which you can do using Java.

Regards,
Rupesh Sinha